# DtypeWarning: Columns (15,16,18,24) have mixed types. Columns get removed if it has mixed type

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
inventory = pd.read_csv('inventory-new.csv', sep=";", names=columns)
```

it says:

> DtypeWarning: Columns (15,16,18,24) have mixed types. Specify dtype
>   option on import or set low_memory=False.
>   interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

and **column numbers 15,16,18,24 gets completely removed**

I tried:

```
inventory = pd.read_csv('inventory-new.csv', sep=";", names=columns, dtype=object)
```

also

```
inventory = pd.read_csv('inventory-new.csv', sep=";", names=columns, low_memory=False)
```

but the result is still the same.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

#### You need to set a dtype for each column.

From the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}
>   Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters
>   are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

#### Why it is happening ?

Most of the time, pandas try to figure out the dtype before processing rows. But if it happens that a value is not of the selected dtype, it will raise an error. Thus you will need to either correct the original data or choose a more permissive dtype to import (like you did with `object`).

Comment: okay, I tried pd.read_csv('rinventory-new.csv', sep=";", names=columns, dtype={1:object, 2:object, 3:object, 4:object.....) but still the problem is same. All the columns with mixed type has gone.

Comment: Can you correct the data before creating the dataframe ? For example using a csv reader ?

Comment: If i take few rows, its fine. But i have 22k rows. Its difficult to find all mixed values

Comment: I guess you could check the types and raise an exception to find the lines. Would you like to update your question with a sample dataset to determine how to do that ?

Comment: I guess my csv file has some problems, I will fix that completely and try it again.